# Image's don't appear in Firefox

Tags: image, firefox

I created a site, http://www.samenwerkendepsychologenamsterdam.nl/
It works fine, the CSS + HTML is not great but it works.

Either way, for the header (the big image) I created an empty fixed size div with a background image.

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div#header {
content:url('images/header1.jpg');
width: 900px;
height: 193px;
margin-top:57px;
}
```

The images appear fine in Safari, Chrome, etc., but not in Firefox.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you use the background property anyway? Why content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [CSS `content` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) is allowed only with the `::after` and `::before` selectors.  You should use `background-image` instead of `content` in your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try `background` instead of `content`